# php_fileinfo extension not working for laravel 4 in online

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

Hi was developing application in laravel having form with file upload fields. Its working perfectly in local system. But when i upload it in online and submit the form its shows this error

```
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available 
(Did you enable the    php_fileinfo extension?)
```

When form submits, i'm checking the extension of the file uploading.

```
Input::file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

I hop 'php_fileinfo' extension in used for getting this file extension.

Please tell me what should i do to overcome this error or is there other way

Comment: Did you install the fileinfo extension?

Comment: Its uploaded in third party shared hosting server. So i don't have control to install that. But in local system its installed.

Comment: There you have your problem. The fileinfo extension is not installed. Contact the server administrator.

Comment: Is there any other way to handle file uploading without 'php_fileinfo'

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation, here's how I worked around it.

> **Caution:** Laravel uses the php_fileinfo stuff is because it follows the principle that you *should never trust the client* - that is, there are risks to blindly trusting the MIME type that the client supplies.

If you are willing to ignore that risk, here's a simple fix, particularly if you only need to handle a single upload

### Implement your own MimeTypeGuesserInterface

This is the interface that Symfony (which Laravel is built on) uses to detect the MIME type of a file. A crucial limitation of this interface is that is only supplies the path of the (temporary) file to guess its type. This means, by the time you get here, the client-supplied MIME type is gone.

```
class StupidMimetypeGuesser implements
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesserInterface
{
    protected $type = null;

    public function __construct($stupidType) {
        $this->type = $stupidType;
    }

    public function guess($path) {
        return $this->type;
    }
}
```

### In your POST handler, manually extract the client-supplied MIME type

```
// This will only work for a single upload. You can implement a fancier guesser to handle multiple files
$attachment = Input::file('attachment');
$clientMime = $attachment->getClientMimeType();

MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance()->register(new StupidMimetypeGuesser($clientMime));
```

Now `Input::file('x')->getMimeType()` will use the client-supplied MIME type.